# NoErrorObjectAvailable : what is the equivalent for contains function in JS

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I'm trying to implement a search functionality in my `Lightning web component`.
This is my function :

```
search(event) {
    this.searchedElImmo = this.allElImmo.filter(function(item) {
            for (const key in item) {
                if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(item, key)) {
                    if (item[key].contains(event.target.value)) {
                        return item;
                    } 
                }
            }


           })  
}
```

I keep getting `NoErrorObjectAvailable`. What is the equivalent of `contains` function in `javascript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

contains() method is not a method of the JavaScript String object. Instead, you can use the includes() method to check if a string contains another string